# I dont know whats wrong with my program but it is definitely wrong

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, pointers, function-pointers

Im a beginner in c++ programming and i wrote this program that supposedly calculate the Pearson Correlation of two column in an array. It was working fine until i try to implement pointers into it. I can compile it and run it but the program always stop after prompting the user to enter the meanx.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

double findCorrelation (int* colx, int* coly, int* ar, double* meanx, double* meany);

int main()
{
//FIND CORRELATION
    double* pearsonCorrelation = new double;
    int num = 1;
    double* meanx = new double;
    double* meany = new double;
    int* colx = new int;
    int* coly = new int;

    const int r = 100;
    const int c = 5;
    int (*ar)[c] = new int[r][c]; 

    for(int row = 0; row <= 100; row++)
    {
        for(int col = 0; col <= 4; col++)
        {
            ar[row][col] = num;
            num++;
        }
    }

    cout << "meanx" << endl;
    cin >> *meanx;

    cout << "meany" << endl;
    cin >> *meany;

    cout << "colx" << endl;
    cin >> *colx;

    cout << "coly" << endl;
    cin >> *coly;

    *pearsonCorrelation = findCorrelation (colx, coly, ar[5], meanx, meany);

    cout << "Pearson is " << pearsonCorrelation << endl << endl << endl << endl;

    return 0;
}

double findCorrelation (int* colx, int* coly, int* ar, double* meanx, double* meany)
{
    double sigmaxy, sigmax2, sigmay2;
    double xy, x2, y2;
    double pearsonCorrelation;

    for(int row = 1; row <= 100; row++)
    {
        xy = (ar[row][colx])*(ar[row][coly]);
        sigmaxy += xy;

        x2 = pow(ar[row][colx], 2);
        sigmax2 += x2;

        y2 = pow(ar[row][coly], 2);
        sigmay2 += y2;
    }

    pearsonCorrelation = (sigmaxy - (100*(*meanx)*(*meany)))/((sqrt(sigmax2-100*pow(*meanx,2))*(sqrt(sigmay2-100*pow(*meany,2)))));

    return pearsonCorrelation;
}
```

The output i get from running this program is this

```
meanx
224.94
```

The program stop after I enter the value for meanx. I don't know whats wrong with my program.

Comment: Why are you dynamically allocating single variables?  C++ is not Java and not C#, so you don't need to dynamically allocate variables, unless you want their lifetime to extend past the execution of a function. Prefer not to use dynamic allocation; it complicates your program and for the most part, unnecessary.

Comment: Prefer to use `std::vector` rather than dynamically allocating arrays.  Dynamic allocation complicates programs; and complicated programs are more difficult to get working.

Comment: You never initialize `meany` nor `nicex`.  Likewise with the column variables.  Make a habit of initializing variables when you declare them.

Comment: Off-topic:  Simplify your program, use `(x * x)` rather than `pow(x,2)`.  The `pow` function requires a calling overhead and at the minimum, a return overhead.  The multiplication is usually 1 instruction.

Comment: FYI, array indices are 0 to N-1.  You'll need to change your loops.

Comment: You can find more issues by using a debugger.